# Get Index of Span if based on the class available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML is as below.

```
 <div class="col-md-12 line">

   <span class="d1  available " seatid="515" seatname="A1"></span>

   <span class="d1  available " seatid="516" seatname="A2"></span>

   <span class="d1  available " seatid="555" seatname="A3"></span>

   <span class="d1  available " seatid="556" seatname="A4"></span>

   <span></span>

   <span class="d1  available " seatid="517" seatname="A5"></span>

   <span class="d1  available " seatid="518" seatname="A6"></span>

 </div>
```

When I click on the span I want to get the index of span comparing to all other spans having same class ,

Which means..

1. Click on before last **span** I need the index as **4**

This is the code I am using to take now.

```
var selector = $(this);
var selectIndex = selector.index();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var selectIndex = selector.parent().children('span.available').index(selector);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should passe the current element to [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get it's index from all the current available span

so you can get the index by using `$("span.available").index($(this))`

PS: avoid using attribute directly on you html tag , you have to use the [data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Attributs_universels/data-*) for both seatid and seatname => (data-seatid   ,  data-seatname ) , you can access those by using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) or [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) in jquery

See below snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $("span.available").on("click",function(){
    console.log("index : " + $("span.available").index($(this)) + " seatid: "+$(this).data('seatid') );
  })
})
```

```css
span {
  display:block;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height:75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 line">

  <span class="d1  available " data-seatid="515" data-seatname="A1">A1</span>

  <span class="d1  available " data-seatid="516" data-seatname="A2">A2</span>

  <span class="d1  available " data-seatid="555" data-seatname="A3">A3</span>

  <span class="d1  available " data-seatid="556" data-seatname="A4">A4</span>

  <span>empty</span>

  <span class="d1  available " data-seatid="517" data-seatname="A5">A5</span>

  <span class="d1  available " data-seatid="518" data-seatname="A6">A6</span>

</div>
```